# How to resize a QTreeView inside a tab, which is in a splitter?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a QTreeView on a tab. The tabs are added to a splitter. When I resize the splitter, the tabs resize, but not the QTreeView inside one of them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create any of the standard layouts in the tab where you are placing your `QTreeView` for objects inside to be placed appropriately. if you are doing this in code you just have to do something like:

```
 QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout (tabWidget->widget (desiredTabNumber));
 layout->addWidget (yourQTreeViewInstance);
```

If you're doing this in designer just go to `QTabWidget`'s tab and select some layout from the top toolbar.